# Convert VB to C# - My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Tags: c#, vb.net

What are the best C# (csharp) equivalents for the following VB (VB.NET, VisualBasic) statements:

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

My.Computer.Clipboard

My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound()

My.Application.Shutdown()
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Application.ExecutablePath

System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard

System.Media.*

Application.Exit

Answer (score 9):

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

My.Computer.Clipboard
  System.Windows.Clipboard //(WPF)
  System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard //(WinForms)

My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound()
  System.Media.SystemSounds.*.Play()

My.Application.Shutdown()
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit() //(WinForms)
  or
  System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown()  //(WPF)
  or
  System.Environment.Exit(ExitCode)  //(Both WinForms & WPF)
```

Comment: These My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory gave different answers for me. The right answer seems to be GetFilePath(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)

Comment: Thanks @user2728841   It is working as excpected. GetFilePath(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location) . It is little bit incorrect. GetExecutingAssembly.Location. Braces () are missing in GetExecutingAssembly() method.

Answer (score 4):

From decompiling Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, the actual code that gets executed when calling `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` is:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(
    new AssemblyInfo(
        Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()).Location);
```

Comment: and My.Application.Info.AssemblyName ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are converting a WPF application, you can use the following:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
//gets file path with file name

System.Windows.Clipboard;

System.Media.SystemSounds.[Sound].Play();

System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but just in case you want to take a shortcut, if you add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly, you can use the nifty tools VB programmers have access via the **MyServices** namespace.

Comment: good shortcut, but yes, I was looking for universal alternatives.  I'm sure this will help someone though.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

is exactly the same as:

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

If you only do:

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

You will get the executing file appended to the path, which may not be useful at all.

Comment: According to [Scuzzlebutt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36102900/1677912), this isn't correct. The GetParent method returns a DirectoryInfo object, not a path (string). You need to use the FullName property to actually get the path. Instead of `System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath) `, use `System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).FullName`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you search is this sentence:

```
Application.StartupPath;
//Get file path without file name.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
using System.IO;
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it is better than the others.